# invalid syntax, if statement. if time < 0

Tags: python, syntax

```
def main():
    get_variables()

def get_variables():
    initial_position = float(input("Enter the object's initial position: "))

    initial_velocity = float(input("Enter the object's initial velocity: "))

    acceleration = float(input("Enter the object's acceleration: "))

    time = float(input("Enter the time that has passed: "))
    if time < 0
        print('The time cannot be negative')
        time = float(input('Enter a valid time: ')

    #formula
    position_of_object = initial_position + initial_velocity * time + 0.5 * acceleration * time ** 2

    #Display Position of object
    print("The position of the object is: ", position_of_object)



    while keep_going == 'y'
        keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another Object's poistion?" + \
                       'position_of_object (Enter y for yes): ') 

main()
```

this is my homework and it says

> "if time < 0
>                 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I barely know anything about programming and am taking an online class on it. Please tell where I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there are few errors in your code:

1:Missing ":" and ")":

```
    if time < 0
        print('The time cannot be negative')
        time = float(input('Enter a valid time: ')
```

Should be changed to:

```
    if time < 0:
        print('The time cannot be negative')
        time = float(input('Enter a valid time: '))
```

2:Missing ":" in wile loop:

```
    while keep_going == 'y'
        keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another Object's 
                      poistion?" + \
                      'position_of_object (Enter y for yes): ')
```

Should be changed into

```
    while keep_going == 'y':
              keep_going = input("Do you want to calculate another Object's 
                    poistion?" + \
                   'position_of_object (Enter y for yes): ')
```